# ReactRouterDom, AuthRoute returns react render functions are not valid as react child warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

My Router is a simple component containing public and private routes. I have created an AuthRoute referring to the great tutorial from [here](https://ui.dev/react-router-v4-protected-routes-authentication/)

So, my Router looks like:

```
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Navigation />
  
        <Route exact path={ROUTES.LANDING} component={Landing} />
        <Route path={ROUTES.SIGN_UP} component={SignUp} />
        <Route path={ROUTES.SIGN_UP_SUCCESS} component={SignUpSuccess} />
        <AuthenticationRoute path={ROUTES.HOME} component={Home} />

      </div>
    </Router>
```

and my AuthenticationRoute looks like this:

```
export const AuthenticationRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  
  const [authChecking, setAuthChecking] = useState(true);
  const [{ isAuth }, dispatch] = useStateValue();

  useEffect(() => {
    checkLoggedIn().then(res => {
      setAuthChecking(false);
      dispatch({
        op: 'auth',
        type: 'toggleSessionAuth',
        toggleSessionAuth: res
      });
    });
  }, [])

  if(authChecking)
    return null;

  if(!isAuth) {
    return <Redirect to='/' />;
  }

    return <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
          <Component {...props} />
      ) 
    } />

}
```

Everything looks fine, however, my console returns such warning:

```
Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from the render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
```

I have tried different solutions using component/render etc, however, I could not find a solution to this problem and I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

For testing purposes, instead of rendering Component, I tried to render simple `<div>test</div>` and it worked fine. However, when I am passing a JSX component in props, it returns the warning shown above.

Implementation oh Home Component (Home.js):

```
export const Home = () => {
    const [{ user }, dispatch] = useStateValue();
    const { history } = useReactRouter();

    const moveTo = path => {
        dispatch({
            op: 'other',
            type: 'setView',
            setView: path
        });
        history.push(path);
    }

    return (
        <div className="pageMenuWrapper">
            <h1 className="homeTitle">Hi {() => user ? `, ${user.username}` : ``}.</h1> 
            <div className="wrapper">
                <Tile image={leagueico} alt="text" onClick={() => moveTo(ROUTES.TEST)}/>  
                <Tile comingSoon />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

Could anyone help me solve this little problem?

Comment: Can you please include implementation of `Home` component that you passed to `AuthenticationRoute`?

Comment: Somehow `Home` is seen as a function and not an actual component. So I want to see how you implemented it.

Comment: @Mosia Thabo, Yeah, sure. It is a functional component, could that be a problem? I put the implementation at the bottom of my question :)

Comment: Thanks, I've looked at it. Sorry for the late response, please check my answer below. That suggestion might be the case here.